# Question about giving feedback to a strict teacher from a student

Tags: phd, thesis, peer-review, professorship, answering-questions

How to give a respectfully feedback to a teacher who is strict enough and  dont want to take classes but always want positive feedback email from her students ?

Comment: The teacher does not want to take classes? I'm not sure what the question is asking.

Comment: she always says  that she is busy

Comment: You mean she is always busy and cannot take care of her students, but in the same time she demands her students to give her good evaluation?

Comment: yes thats what i am saying

Comment: and on the basis of that mail she will give marks

Answer (score 1):

In short: you approach her boss with exactly this question. E.g., the dean.

Comment: i want a format  that how to write it

Comment: @shashwatsingh - You say that you have a "concern" and you ask for an appointment.  Then you lay out the information in your meeting with the dean.